# Removing square brackets in pandas python export of numpy array to excel

Tags: python, pandas

Using the following function:

```
def exportExcel(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    filepath = 'Output.xlsx'
    df.to_excel(filepath, index=False)
```

Output after exporting the np.array to excel columns

```
    column a       column b     column c
    [[0.00536237] [0.00536237]] [0.01030928]
    [[0.00652899] [0.00652899]] [0.]
    [[0.00579218] [0.00579218]] [0.]
```

How can I remove all the squared brackets?

I have tried several solutions, but they don´t work:

```
for col in df:
df[col] = df[col].str.extract(r'\[(.*)\]')
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you see for `type(df['column a'].iloc[0])` ? It's important to know whether you have strings, a list, an array, or something else.

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column is in numpy, you can make use of the function np.squeeze()

```
df[col]=np.squeeze(df[col].tolist())
```

Answer (score 2):

If they are `string`, you can use `replace`:

```
df[col] = df[col].str.replace('[','')
df[col] = df[col].str.replace(']','')
```

Or if the square brackets you want to remove are only at the start or end of the string, with `strip`:

```
df[col] = df[col].str.strip('[')
df[col] = df[col].str.strip(']')
```

Comment: I see this: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: What type are the columns? see jpp comment

Comment: I can´t see the type

Comment: they are the square brackets of a numpy array

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: how is the df before to export it to excel? i think it should be modified then